# How can I increase my validation accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I am working on a word-based sign language recognition system. I'm new to deep learning. My experience is limited. I have 10 classes. The size of the data ( 1256, 32, 112, 112, 3). For video classification I use 3D CNN, which has been mentioned in articles as being better than lstm's. My model couldn't learn at first. Or it was overfitting. I made some improvements. Using batchnormalization instead of Dropout in feature learning layers, keeping the learning_rate high at first and then lowering it, lowering the total parameter of my model. These were the improvements I tried. And results have improved. But in my test results, while acc is 0.69, my loss value is 1.02, which is very high. What improvements should I make for better results in this regard, do you have any recommendations? Below is the information about my model and its outputs.

[Model accuracy and model loss graphs is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0E8b.png)

[My Model is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLOFD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is your model based on other popular model?
You could try using a transfer learning model reusing low level layers. Also increasing your data and setting a different batch size can help